# WebBrowser control - wait for page loading after submit form

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, synchronous

I am new to c# and its concepts, so i am sorry if this question is kind of dumb.
I try to do some automatation using the winforms webbrowser control

```
elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
{
    if (element.GetAttribute("value") == "Anzeigen")
    element.InvokeMember("click");
}

while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) Application.DoEvents();

// do some math on recived html
// ......

// show results
MessageBox.Show(numPlanets.ToString() );
```

So, to explain it: 
Im looking for a Button with the value "Anzeigen", simulate a click on it, then wait till NEW page is loaded and do my calculations then.
Unfortunately my calculations are done on the OLD HTML content, because its not waiting for the page to load. Strangely if i enter an Thread.Sleep(5000); after the foreach loop, this Sleep is executed BEFORE the click is simulated, and the calculation fails also.

I just need some synchronous behavior for that click, withouth using an event.

Hope u can help me with that, sorry for my bad english

EDIT:
Solved it like this:
Variable bool webbbrowserfinished = false inside the class, if i want synchronous behavior, i do it like this:

```
   webbrowserfinished = false;
   // do navigation here

   while (!webbrowserfinished)
   {
      Application.DoEvents();
      Thread.Sleep(100);
   }
   webbrowserfinished = false;
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use event?

Comment: This is not possible, IMO. I've used the web browser control _a lot_, including in [edit mode](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43954/ZetaHtmlEditControl). I've never found a synchron solution, since I do think the loading simply takes place asynchronously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx)
Occurs when the WebBrowser control finishes loading a document.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   webBrowser1.Navigate("google.com");
   webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
}

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Completed Now!");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately he said "without using an event".

Comment: My problem with events is, i have to do this over and over again. I go to a new page, do the math, go to a new page, do the math, go to a new page.... i think this cant be solved elegant with an event, correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Well it isn't the best of solutions but you could always start a timer when the web browser navigates, and set `timer1.Tick` to something like 3000, then within the `timer1_Tick` method you can do your calculations on the new page, and then `timer1.Stop();`.

There is probably a better solution using events but I'm not too good with web browsers myself.

Comment: This seems to use events, too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thread.sleep(5000)` to wait for your page to load, because if you don't, the navigate method will load a new doc into web browser control but it will not call `document_complete_event_handler`